# undefined method `relation_delegate_class'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have three models:

```
class Course < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :sections
end

class Section < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :course
  has_many :section_files
end

class SectionFile < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :section
end
```

Whenever I try to call `@course.sections` I receive the error `undefined method 'relation_delegate_class' for Course::Section:Module`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed my specifying the class name on Section

```
Class Course < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :sections, class_name: "::Section"
end
```

Although, `@section.section_files` seems to work without having to explicitly state the class name

Comment: Nice, thanks! I had _exactly_ the same error situation, all models global (outside of modules), all derived from ApplicationRecord, and for some reason just one relation would not work. Did you figure out the reason for this issue? I'm happy to apply the fix but I'd prefer to also understand why it is necessary here.